# What's behind placing condition in left join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 similar select statements which return different amount of rows.

SELECT #1:

```
select count(*)
from table_1 a
    left join table_2 b
        on a.column_1 = b.column_1 
        and b.column_2 = 1
where b.column_1 is null
    and a.column_2 = 2;

76782 rows returned
```

SELECT #2:

```
select count(*)
from table_1 a
    left join table_2 b
        on a.column_1 = b.column_1
        and a.column_2 = 2
        and b.column_2 = 1
where b.column_1 is null;

307778 rows returned
```

DB versin is Oracle 12.2.0.1.0

Can someone explain what's behind the 2 select statements that returns different number of rows, please?

Comment: If you put non-null conditions of the left joined table in the `where` clause then it turns into an `inner join`

Answer (score 1):

**Select #1:**

- The condition `b.column_2 = 1` is applied to `table_1` prior to left joining,
- the conditions `a.column_2 = 2` and `b.column_1 is null` are applied to the data set after all (outer) joins are applied.

I.e., the query does:

1. Loop through all `table_1` rows satisfying the condition `table_1.column_2 = 2`, then
2. try and find the rows of `table_2` satisfying the condition `table_2.column_2 = 1` and left outer join them with the `table_1` on `column_1`, then
3. filter the resulting rows so that you keep only those rows satisfying the after-outer-join-condition `table_2.column_1 is null`.

**Select #2:**

- The condition `b.column_2 = 1` is applied to `table_1` prior to left joining,
- the condition `a.column_1 = 2` acts as a joining predicate, i.e. it's saying "find matching rows only when `a.column_1 = 2`,
- the condition `b.column_1 is null` is applied to the data set after all (outer) joins are applied.

I.e., the query does:

1. Loop through all `table_1` rows satisfying the condition `table_1.column_2 = 2`, then
2. try and find the rows of `table_2` satisfying the condition `table_2.column_2 = 1` and left outer join them with the `table_1` on `column_1`, but only for the `table_1` rows satisfying the condition `table_1.column_1 = 2`,
3. filter the resulting rows so that you keep only those rows satisfying the after-outer-join-condition `table_2.column_1 is null`

**Notes:**

What's happening "behind the scenes", can actually be best inspected when looking at the queries' execution plans, focusing your attention more towards the "access/filter predicates" section(s) of them. It's actually a good, general advice: When you don't understand something about the query you see, look at its execution plan, it's much more "imperative language"-like.

Answer (score 0):

The first filters by `a.column_2 = 2` because it is in the `where` clause.

The second has no filter on `a`.  Why?  Because the `a.column_2 = 2`.  Even when this is not true, a row is returned, because this is a `left join` with `a` as the first table.

What should happen, though, is that any columns from `a` are `NULL` for the non-`2` rows.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are doing an **anti-join**, where `b.column_1 is null` excludes all rows in `table_1` which match the join conditions. Moving a condition into the join makes the join more restrictive, so the anti-join excludes *less* rows.

I sometimes find it more intuitive to re-write anti-joins as `not exists`:

Select #1:

```
select count(*)
from table_1 a
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table_2 b
                  where a.column_1 = b.column_1 
                    and b.column_2 = 1)
  and a.column_2 = 2;
```

Select #2:

```
select count(*)
from table_1 a
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table_2 b
                  where a.column_1 = b.column_1 
                    and b.column_2 = 1
                    and a.column_2 = 2);
```

Which you could rewrite as:

```
select count(*)
from table_1 a
where (a.column_2 = 2 
       and not exists (select 1 
                  from table_2 b
                  where a.column_1 = b.column_1 
                    and b.column_2 = 1)
      )
   OR a.column_2 <> 2;
```

Which is clearly a lot less restrictive than Select #1.